# "Throttling navigation to prevent the browser from hanging" appearing in my Vite/React/IIS(Internet Information Services) and application not working

Tags: reactjs, iis, routes, deployment, vite

I have built a Vite React app this is being hosted on a IIS (Internet Information Services) server. The link to get to the app works fine and I can do a few things on the homepage, but soon I get the error "Throttling navigation to prevent the browser from hanging. See https://crbug.com/1038223. Command line switch --disable-ipc-flooding-protection can be used to bypass the protection".

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I've been all over my config files and Routes file and cannot correct the problem.

Comment: It seems like your app is going in a loop, you need to open the debugger and step through your code execution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.